# Lightning Icon Background color not changing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, svg-icon

I have a lightning icon in my lightning component. It is an icon of type standard and I want to change its color:

Component

```
<div class="slds-media__figure">
    <lightning:icon iconName="standard:currency" class="cashAccountIcon" size="small"/>
</div>
```

Controller

```
.THIS.cashAccountIcon svg {
    fill : red;
}
```

However, the color is not changing in the above code. Is that a problem with my code or we cannot change backgrounds of standard icons?

Comment: You should be able to change the colors via CSS.  I suggest trying `.THIS .cashAccountIcon svg {` with a space between .THIS and .cashAccountIcon to start

Comment: That did the trick. I get very confused as to when there should be a space and when there shouldn't. Anyways, please put this in Answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.THIS.myClass`, with the period attaching `THIS` and `myClass` tries to look for the root element and whether it has `myClass` associated with it.  Assuming your icon is not the root element in the component, try using `.THIS .cashAccountIcon svg {` with a space between `.THIS` and `.cashAccountIcon`

For what it's worth, if you use VS Code, you can hover over the `.THIS ...` line of code and see what kind of document structure it is trying to apply the CSS to.

Comment: I understand. Thanks.